# How to compare month and year to datetime in sqlite ios

Tags: ios, datetime, sqlite

When I test this query directly in sqlite manager, it shows the result well, but when I test it with iphone simulator, it shows like this:

[image: query]

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: type of column 'dateOrder' is datetime !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the `%` characters in your SQL so that `stringWithFormat` knows not to try to substitute values for them.  Like:

```
NSString* select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from orders where isPaid = 1 and strftime('%%Y-%%m',dateOrder) = '%@'",dateString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace code query with following

```
NSString* select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from orders where isPaid = 1 and strftime('%%Y-%%m',dateOrder) = '%@'",dateString];
```

Comment: Thank you, it is the same as the above answer !